# How can I use google search operators to exclude website paths?

Tags: google-search

I am looking for a google search operator pattern that searches for links without a path attached/query.

I have been looking around the internet, looking into google search operators, trying out multiple patterns, and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

```
What should work: https://example.com, http://example.com, https://example.io
What shouldn't work: https://example.com/path, http://example.com/path?query=True, https://example.io/path, https://example.com?query=True
```

I have tried all of these:

```
-inurl:(com|io)/_
inurl:(com|io)/-_
-inurl:(com|io)/*
inurl:(com|io)/-*
-inurl:com/_
```

etc with +, using only io or com, including "?" after /, and using "allinurl:" and "site:"

Nothing gave me the results I wanted.

any help is appreciated

Comment: consider changing browser?..

Comment: PS: so in other words you are saying you want only the homepage?

Comment: Questions on **the use of third party web applications** are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se]. I recommend reading their [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com//about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Comment: @JohnConde thanks! The only way I could think to ask questions was on stack overflow.

Comment: I have the same issue but no solution